# Google Admob doesn't show in flutter web-view App

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

I've a webView flutter app that contains ads, this is not my first time using admob with flutter, it always show "Failed to load ad:" , I've searched a lot but with no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many reasons for this

1. AdMob Id is not true in AndroidManifest
2. is not added in AndroidManifest
3. ad loads before the screen is loaded
4. in the last try to change the name of application id and reinstall app